# How is this probability distribution evaluated with Kronecker Delta and summation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation, kronecker-delta

I am reading through Robert Swendsen's *An Introduction to Statistical Mechanics and Thermodynamics*, and in section 3.4, he provided an example of the probability of the sum of two dice using Kronecker delta, I am extremely lost on the latter half of this example.

So we have two dice with 6 sides on each dice, let $X=\{x|x=1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ represent random number outcome of first die, and $Y$ represent second die.

Let $S=X+Y$ be the sum, with values range from $2$ to $12$.

Let the probability distribution be $$P(x,y)=P_{X}(x)P_{Y}(x)=(\frac{1}{6})(\frac{1}{6})=\frac{1}{36}$$

Now we evaluate $P(s)$ using Kronecker Delta, $$P(s)=\frac{1}{36}\sum_{x=1}^{6}\sum_{y=1}^{6}\delta_{s,x+y}$$

First, evaluate the sum over $y$:
$$\sum_{y=1}^{6}\delta_{s,x+y}=\begin{cases} 
      1 & 1\leq s-x \leq 6 \\
      0 & otherwise
   \end{cases}$$

Only for $y$ within interval $[1,6]$ does the Kronecker Delta has a value.

Because of this, the value of $x$ is limited by $$s-6 \leq x \leq s-1$$, further more, $x$ must satisfy $$1 \leq x \leq 6$$.

Robert then proposed the following:
$$P(s)=\begin{cases} 
      \sum_{x=1}^{s-1} \frac{1}{36} =\frac{s-1}{36} & s \leq 7 \\
      \sum_{x=s-1}^{6} \frac{1}{36} =\frac{13-s}{36} & s \geq 7
   \end{cases}$$

How was $P(s)$ evaluated over the sum at the end? I feel like I am missing something obvious here but my brain can't figure it out.

Normally, I would expect something like this: $$\sum_{i=1}^{3} 2i+1=[2(1)+1]+[2(2)+1]+[2(3)+1]=15$$

But I am not sure how to evaluate $$\sum_{x=s-6}^{6} \frac{1}{36} =\frac{13-s}{36} \,\,\, s \geq 7$$ ?

**Edit: here's a screenshot of the original text**
[image]

Comment: Presumably you mean $P_Y(y)$ where you wrote $P_Y(x).$

Comment: I suspected it's $P_Y(y)$ too, but the original text says $P_Y(x)$

Comment: Are you sure it's not $8-s$ instead of $13-s$

Comment: @whoisit The original text says $13-s$

Comment: You should write the lower bound of the last summation as $s-6$ instead of $s-1$

Comment: @whoisit thank you, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be integers, $a>b$.

Then, for any constant $c$, one can easily prove that: $$\sum_{i=a}^b c = c(b-a+1)$$

This fact is being used in the last two summations.

Comment: Is there a name for this rule?

Comment: It's just counting - You are basically counting the number of times the constant is being added to itself.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the late reply. Did you mean $a<b$?